# Location permission on iOS in react-native not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation

No Location Permission pop up in ios app nor can see Permissions options in the settings of the App

Works fine on Android. As I can use PermissionsAndroid to get the permissions.

Already used the following options in the info.plist by looking at the other answers. Few answers only mentioned about android.

```
info.plist

<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Location Permission</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Location Permission</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>GPS data is required to...</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Location Permission</string>

codeinthefile.js

try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
            title: "Geolocation Permission",
            message: "App needs access to your phone's location.",
        }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                Geocoder.from({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                })
                    .then(json => {
                        console.log(json);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
        );
    } else {
        console.log('Location permission not granted!);
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Location permission not granted!)
}
```

If by using the above-mentioned values in info.plist I should get the access to location then there should not be an error of no permission granted.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew for the reply. I have checked this library too. But what is that this library is doing that cant be done by default in react-native? Also I have to use Async storage with the library to not always ask about the permissions. Seemed like not an appropriate solution.

Comment: 'react-native-permissions' will not ask again if you agree with the permission.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use PermissionAndroid in iOS, is enough to put the permission requirement in the info.plist,

try something like,

```
if(Platform.OS === "ios"){
   // your code using Geolocation and asking for authorisation with

   geolocation.requestAuthorization()
}else{
   // ask for PermissionAndroid as written in your code
}
```

Comment: For ios, you ask for permissions with `geolocation.requestAuthorization();` using the React Native Geolocation. This will request the level of permissions set in the info.plist. From the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/geolocation

Comment: Yes, exactly. The problem that he has is that is using PermissionsAndroid in iOS , that is returning null probably. He instead has to use geolocation directly, asking for authorisation with it.

Comment: I still have the problem

Answer (score 6):

Thank you, Doug and David, Based on your suggestion I have made then changes to my code in the following way which worked for me:

```
if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
    Geolocation.requestAuthorization();
    this.getGeoLocation();
}else {

    let granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
            title: "App Geolocation Permission",
            message: "App needs access to your phone's location.",
        }
    );

    if (androidGranted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

        this.getGeoLocation();

    } else {

        console.log('Location permission not granted!!!!');

    }

}
```

Comment: Does this work on ios emulator, or should i use a real device for test?

Comment: No, it doesn't work on emulator, you will have to use the actual Device.

Comment: How do you check if permission was granted on iOS?

Comment: You have to set Always and When in Usage key in the info.plist in Xcode and this will give truthy value when you are checking in the above code.

Answer (score 3):

Use below for both android and ios permissions .

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import {request, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';
....

export async function getLocationPermissions() {
  const granted = await request(
    Platform.select({
      android: PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
      ios: PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE,
    }),
    {
      title: 'DemoApp',
      message: 'DemoApp would like access to your location ',
    },
  );

  return granted === RESULTS.GRANTED;
}

....
// usage
const granted = await getLocationPermissions();
```